# Trying to join the closest line of a table to another table

Tags: sql, join, firebird

I have 2 tables and I want to join the highest but not over revision line of table b into table a

Table a:

```
REVISION_NO     INFO1
1               a
2               b
3               c
4               d
5               e
6               f
```

Table b:

```
REVISION_NO     INFO2
1               x
4               y
6               z
```

I want :

```
a               x
b               x
c               x
d               y
e               y
f               z
```

Some join expert knows how to make this happen ? If it matters, the database is Firebird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working solution for SQL Server 2008.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @a TABLE(REVISION_NO INT, INFO1 CHAR(1))
DECLARE @b TABLE(REVISION_NO INT, INFO2 CHAR(1))
INSERT INTO @a VALUES
(1, 'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c'),(4,'d'),(5,'e'),(6,'e')
INSERT INTO @b VALUES
(1,'x'),(4,'y'),(6,'z')
--
SELECT a.INFO1
, ISNULL(b.INFO2, (
    SELECT INFO2 FROM @b WHERE REVISION_NO = (
        SELECT MAX(REVISION_NO) 
        FROM @b 
        WHERE REVISION_NO < a.REVISION_NO
))) [INFO2]
FROM @a a
LEFT JOIN @b b 
    ON b.REVISION_NO = a.REVISION_NO
END
```

Don't know if firebird will allow such next queries

Comment: Thanks, I managed to do what I wanted from your solution even if I didn't fully understood the "ISNULL" part and "[INFO2]".

Comment: @Nalmar - The names in the brackets [name] are just column alias/headers for the output. ISNULL is used becuase I used a LEFT JOIN which will return NULL values for b columns, and if they are NULL then we look up the proper value using the inner query.

Answer (score -1):

just sql:

```
select a.info01, b.info02
  from a
       inner join b on b.revision_no = (select max(revision_no) 
                                          from b 
                                         where revision_no <= a.revision_no)
```

which returns:

```
INFO01 INFO02
====== ======
a      x
b      x
c      x
d      y
e      y
f      z
```